# Adding an integer octet to a byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, byte, rfc

I am trying to implement Salted Challenge Response Authentication Mechanism ([RFC 5802](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802)) and I am running into a bit of a problem.

```
Hi(str, salt, i):

U1   := HMAC(str, salt + INT(1))
U2   := HMAC(str, U1)
...
Ui-1 := HMAC(str, Ui-2)
Ui   := HMAC(str, Ui-1)

Hi := U1 XOR U2 XOR ... XOR Ui

where "i" is the iteration count, "+" is the string concatenation
operator, and INT(g) is a 4-octet encoding of the integer g, most
significant octet first.
```

I am unsure of how to add the INT(1). I have a byte array for salt. Do all I need to do is bit shift the 1 and add it to the end of the array?

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought to make that a link.

Comment: It looks to me like it's simply the binary sequence `00,00,00,01`. That's the 4-octet encoding of the integer 1, with the most significant octet first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add anything to an array. As arrays are fixed size you need to create a new array for the result. Use the `BitConverter` class to get the binary representation of the integer:

```
// create new array
byte[] key = new byte[salt.Length + 4];
// copy salt
Array.Copy(salt, key, salt.Length);
// create array from integer
byte[] g = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(g);
}
// copy integer array
Array.Copy(g, 0, key, salt.Length, 4);
```

Comment: Thank you. Looking at it there is an easier way but this works.

Comment: @Coder2000: Yes, there are other ways to do the same way, for example using extension methods to merge the data from the arrays and turn it into a new array.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of Array.Copy(new byte[] { 0,0,0,1 }, 0, salt.Length, 4);

Comment: @Coder2000: You could even make use of the fact that the array is zero filled when created, so you don't have to copy the zero bytes. You would get away with just `key[salt.Length + 3]++;` :)